# module FMICAPI: Could not load the FMU binary: The specified module could not be found

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, fmi

I am exporting an fmu with CVODE solver, from OpenModelica Windows v1.22.1 and trying to run a simulation through OMSimulator on Python. I get the following error (I have removed the model name from the error message):

```
[fmiLogger] module FMICAPI: Could not load the FMU binary: The specified module could not be found. 
[instantiate] Could not load "resources/xxx.fmu" which is associated with Model; it may be corrupted or may not support your platform
error:   [initialize] Model is in wrong model state
error:   [simulate] Model is in wrong model state
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Looks like it cannot load the FMU dynamic link library in the OMSimulator process. What operating system are you on? Linux? Windows? Mac? Have you tried the FMU directly with OMSimulator, not via Python: OMSimulator Model.fmu?

Comment: @AdrianPop I am on Windows. I have not tried the FMU directly with OMSimulator. I will try it and report back. Few things that I tried are :
-Export FMU and run the same code using OMSimulator on python in Linux -- it works fine
-Export FMU with OpenModelica older version (v1.21) -- always gave an error at oms.terminate() saying "OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000000xyz"

Is there something I have to add for OMSimulator process to load the dll?
I am using python version 3.11.7

Comment: @AdrianPop I just tried your suggestion. It works fine directly with OMSimulator. So it seems that the issue is only with OmSimulator via Python on Windows.

Comment: This seems like a bug, I will check what is going on.

Comment: See https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/12065